# Python and EAFP principle: any way of differentiating betweeen 2 exceptions of the same type?

Tags: python, exception

I have following code:

```
    try:
        player.board[move][player.board[move].index(None)] = chosen_card
        player.cards.remove(chosen_card)
    except ValueError:
        print("This row already has 3 cards!") # There is no None in array
        print("Player doesn't have such card!") # can't remove a card player doesn't have
    except IndexError:
        print("Invalid board index") # move is bigger than 9 or smaller than 0
```

the part:

```
player.board[int(move)].index(None)
```

can throw a ValueError if there is no *None* in an array.

The part

```
player.cards.remove(chosen_card)
```

can also throw ValueError if there is no such object to be removed.

Is there any way to know exactly what threw ValueError and handle it (ex. if this did it -> do this if that did it -> do that)?

I tried splitting those lines into two try except blocks, but then if the second block throws an exception, the first one executes (the card is put on a board) and it shouldn't since the player didn't have the card.

I know I can check all of these conditions first and then execute, but I want to program everything in pythonic way with EAFP principle in mind.

Also if there is a better design idea to program this part, please share as well.

Comment: If you are in control of the code raising the exceptions, I would switch to raising exceptions from separate *subclasses* of `ValueError`, eliminating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, probably not the most simple, would be creating a custom class just to achieve what you want. It's a common way to throw a more pythonic error to be catchable by the developer.

i.e.:

```
class BoardValueError(ValueError):
    pass
```

With this, you can also use a try/except inside try/except clause, to differentiate both exceptions.

(This class from the example could be catchable by using either `BoardValueError` or `ValueError`, or any of it's *parents*)

As a note: On one block try/except, even if the second instruction throws an error, this wouldn't "rollback" the first one. So card would still be added to the board. You may need to implement a rollback logic inside your program, using two exception blocks wouldn't change much, and would probably be the most simple way to do it.